# Calling click event handler from code

Tags: javascript, event-handling

We use the [formassembly](https://www.formassembly.com/) app to build hosted webforms.

FormAssembly offers conditional rules to show/hide sections.  They also offer the ability to add custom Javascript to their form.

I want to use their native functionality to hide some sections, but I need to trigger this via javascript.

I have setup [this form](https://www.tfaforms.com/4650984) so that when 'scholarship' = 'yes', then the payment details section is hidden.

I have added some js so that if discount code = 'comp' then amount = 0 and scholarship = 'yes'.  However, this change does not cause the payment details section to be hidden.

From chrome dev console I can see that this radio button has an event handler set for clicks, which must be the reason for the difference in behavior.  So I'm inquiring whether there is a clean way to call the event handler from my code?

My code is very simple, and is called by setting a value in the discount code input field.

```
<script>
  function setPrice(base,code) {
    var calcprice = base;
     var lcc;
    // test if code is not null
    if (code){
     lcc = code.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (lcc == 'comp'){
        calcprice = 0;
        }        
    else if (code) {
      calcprice = 'Invalid Code'; 
    }
    else {
      calcprice = calcprice;}

    if (calcprice == 0){       
      document.getElementById("tfa_715").checked = true;
    }
    return calcprice;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it right but it seems you only asked for this: `document.getElementById("tfa_715").click();`.

Comment: that nails it.  thank you!  much appreciated.